# Bootstrap Timepicker with Current Time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I have used Bootstrap Time Picker and below is the code :

```
jQuery('#timePicker').timepicker();
```

I wanted to display the by default time to current time + 6 hrs.. i.e, if current time is 13.00 then time to display on timepicker should be 13.00 + 06.00 = 19.00hrs

is there any way to do this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'setTime'` method of **timepicker** and increased the time by 6 hours by converting current time and 6 hours into **milliseconds** and back to date variable

```js
$('#timepicker').timepicker();

 $('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', new Date(new Date().getTime()+6*3600*1000));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.js
"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<input id="timepicker" class="time ui-timepicker-input" autocomplete="off">
```

**ADD:**

Working Code with bootstrap timepicker

```js
$('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', new Date(new Date().getTime()+6*3600*1000));
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');/*!
 * Timepicker Component for Twitter Bootstrap
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Joris de Wit
 *
 * Contributors https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/graphs/contributors
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
.bootstrap-timepicker {
  position: relative;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker.pull-right .bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker.pull-right .bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu:before {
  left: auto;
  right: 12px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker.pull-right .bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 13px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker .input-group-addon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker .input-group-addon i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 4px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.open {
  display: inline-block;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu:before {
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu:after {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-left:before {
  left: 6px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-left:after {
  left: 7px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-right:before {
  right: 6px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-right:after {
  right: 7px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-top:before {
  top: -7px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-top:after {
  top: -6px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-bottom:before {
  bottom: -7px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid #999;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.timepicker-orient-bottom:after {
  bottom: -6px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 6px solid #ffffff;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget a.btn,
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget input {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table td {
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table td:not(.separator) {
  min-width: 30px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table td span {
  width: 100%;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table td a {
  border: 1px transparent solid;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  outline: 0;
  color: #333;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table td a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table td a i {
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table td input {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.bootstrap-timepicker-widget .modal-content {
  padding: 4px;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .bootstrap-timepicker-widget.modal {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .bootstrap-timepicker {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .bootstrap-timepicker .dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
 <input type="text" id="timepicker">
```

Comment: hmmm..need to call `$('#timepicker').timepicker();` before setting time

Comment: i m using bootstrap timepicker

Comment: ankit thanx, i have changed the bootstrap timepicker to Jquery normal timepicker... that worked..